# WIN 10 always use default USB driver INF file

Tags: usb, windows-10, inf

My USB device is set as CDC. If the USB is set as CDC, the windows 10 will auto use default INF file(Usbser.inf). How can I change the default INF file to myself INF file?

Comment: Same issue here, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to instruct your users to install your INF file before plugging in the device.  Once your INF file is installed, it will be used by default.  If your INF file is not installed, usbser.inf and usbser.sys are used by default for matching USB devices.

Comment: I have installed my INF file, but the WIN 10 still use the default INF file. How to fix this?

Comment: Select the device in the Device Manager, right click, Update Driver Software, and tell Windows to automatically find new drivers.  It should find your INF.